# Ross, Elementary Analysis S19 Example 3 - Question about inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I am working my way through Ross, Elementary Analysis for an Intro to Analysis Course. I am confused by something in this example:
[image: Ross Elementary Analysis 3e S19 Example 3]

We wish to show that for each (every) $\delta>0$ there exists $x,y$....

So after equation (3), why is it sufficient to to prove (1) for $\delta<\frac{1}{2}$?

I understand that if $x,y\in\left(0,1\right)$, then $\left|x-y \right|<1$, but I don't understand why we can use a tighter bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to prove that for however small $\delta$, you can find two points at with distance less than $\delta$ such that distance between their images remains large(greater than $1$). So it suffices to prove it for $\delta$ less than a fixed quantity, say $\frac 12$.

**Edit:** Mathematically, suppose one has proved that for every $0<\delta<\frac 12$ there exists $x,y \in (0,1)$ such that $$|x-y|<\delta \text{ and yet } |f(x)-f(y)|\geq1$$

Now, let $\delta \geq \frac12$.

By above hypothesis, there exists $x,y \in (0,1)$ such that $$|x-y|<\frac14\text{ and yet } |f(x)-f(y)|\geq1$$

As $\delta>\frac14$ hence,  $$|x-y|<\delta\text{ and yet } |f(x)-f(y)|\geq1$$